# How to get the mode of a text[] in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a table, I have a column of type text[]. I want to extract the most frequent string in each row. How can I do that?

Trivial example:

```
id | fruit
----------------------------------
10 | ['apple','pear','apple']   
20 | ['pear','pear','banana']   
30 | ['pineapple','apple','apple']
```

After running the query I would like to have:

```
id | fruit                        | mode
-----------------------------------------
10 | ['apple','pear','apple']     | apple
20 | ['pear','pear','banana']     | pear
30 | ['pineapple','apple','apple']| apple
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Are you guaranteed that each row has a single unique mode value? If not, what are you expecting in those cases?

Comment: The sample data looks more like the column is defined as `jsonb` rather than `text[]` - which data type is it really?

Comment: *Don't* use such fields in the first place. If you want to query those values (and aggregating *is* querying) they should be in separate fields. You'll have to convert these values in proper rows to `GROUP` and calculate `COUNT()` anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a scalar sub-query after unnesting the elements:

```
select *, 
       (select mode() within group (order by u.word)
        from unnest(u.fruit) as u(word)) as mode
from the_table t
```

This assumes that `fruit` is a `text[]` column. If it's a `json` or `jsonb` in reality, you need to use `json_array_elements_text()` instead of unnest.

If you need that a lot, you can create a function for that.